# loading xml tags into html file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an xml file that I need to load into my html file so I can present the xml data on my html page.

This is the HTML, using javascript to load the file.

```
<script>

function displaySYMBOL()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","stock.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("finance");
i=0;

symbol=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("symbol")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.getElementById("showSYMBOL").innerHTML=symbol;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displaySYMBOL()">

<div id="mainpage">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="showSYMBOL">test</div>
    <div id="stock2">Location Test</div>
    <div id="stock3"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the xml

```
<xml_api_reply version="1">
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
<finance module_id="0" tab_id="0" mobile_row="0" mobile_zipped="1" row="0" section="0">
<symbol data="XLNX"/>
<pretty_symbol data="XLNX"/>
<company data="Xilinx, Inc."/>
<exchange data="Nasdaq"/>
<exchange_closing data="52.89"/>
<last data="52.55"/>
<high data="53"/>
<low data="51.99"/>
<volume data="6158738"/>
<open data="52.51"/>
<y_close data="52.89"/>
<change data="-0.34"/>
<perc_change data="-0.64"/>
</finance>
</xml_api_reply>
```

Ultimately the symbol data should be displayed with the showSYMBOL div tag in the HTML. Currently that is not happening. What am I missing?

Comment: So is `symbol` set with the value you're expecting from `x[i].getElementsByTagName("symbol")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue`?

Comment: The value I want symbol set at is the "XLNX" from the xml sheet.

Comment: See my answer below, check the jsfiddle. I think that's what you're looking for?

Comment: That's totally it. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not the `nodeValue` you're looking for:

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
} else {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(xml); 
}

console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("symbol")[0].getAttribute('data'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jorgthuijls/HBgka/1/

Answer (score 0):

### You want the attribute value

replace this

```
symbol=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("symbol")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

with this

```
symbol=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("symbol")[0].getAttribute("data"));
```